# function has global maximum

Tags: calculus

I have to show that, if f function with R->R, continuous and f(x)->0 for |x|->infinity, then f has a global maximum. But I have counterexample. f(x)=1/(e^x). This function satisfies all conditions, but has not a global maximum. Am I right?

Comment: No, $f(x) = 1/e^x = e^{-x}$ does *not* converge to zero if $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $f(x) \to 0$ for $|x| \to \infty$ means $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = 0$ **and**  $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @MartinR ahhh. Sorry, I understood this wrong.. Ok, thank you. Can you give advice, how to proof it? What I have to begin with? What is the idea?

Comment: @nikibiki: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041551/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1540479/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632029/42969

Comment: @MartinR yes, super. Thank u